# SUM of DISTINCTCOUNT

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to sum of different suppliers by produt_id, below is an example of table:

| product_id | supplier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | E |
| 4 | E |
| 5 | C |
| 5 | F |
| 5 | F |

In the table I have other elements, but these columns are the relevant ones for the count.
The answer I'm looking for is 10, I try to explain in the table below:

| product_id | DistinctCount(supplier) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 |

Total = 2 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 2 = 10

Thanks in advance!

I tried several different ways and I couldn't. I hope I can solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 measures will solve your problem

```
Count Supplier = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[supplier])
```

and

```
Sum Count Supplyer = 
SUMX( 
    DISTINCT( 'Table'[product_id] ), 
    [Count Supplier]
)
```

[image]

The Total of Count Supplier is the number of distinct suppliers in the whole table, ignoring the grouping.